# How to display pie slice data and tooltip together using chart.js

Tags: pie-chart, chart.js

[image]

Can we display data in pie chart slice and also tolltip like the above image using chart.js?

Updated:

Here is my code in php page.

```
            printf( '<table>' );
            echo '<tr><td style="text-align: right;"><canvas id="pie-canvas-'
                 . $canvasId
                 . '" width=256px height=257px ></canvas></td><td style="text-align: left;width:360px;" id="legend" class="chart-legend"></td></tr>';

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">drawPie('
                . $canvasId
                . ', '
                . $data
                .', '
                . $legend
                . ');</script>';
            printf( '</table>' );

printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="extlib/Chart.min.js"></script>' );
printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="extlib/jquery-min.js"></script>' );
printf( '<script type="text/javascript">' );
?>
function drawPie( canvasId, data, legend )
{
//pie chart for machine status
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "pie-canvas-" + canvasId );
    var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
    var midX = canvas.width/2;
    var midY = canvas.height/2;
    var piedata = [];

    $.each(data,function(i,val){
        piedata.push({value:val.hostStatusCount,color:val.color,label:val.status});
    });

    Chart.types.Pie.extend({
        name: "PieAlt",
        draw: function(){
            Chart.types.Pie.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
            drawSegmentValues(this)
        }
    });
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).PieAlt(piedata, {
        showTooltips: true,
        tooltipTemplate: "<%= Math.round(circumference / 6.283 * 100) %>%"

    });

    var radius = myPieChart.outerRadius;

    function drawSegmentValues(myPieChart)
    {
    //displays segements(number of machines) for each slice of pie in percentage
        var length = myPieChart.segments.length;
        var totalValue = 0;
        for ( var i=0; i < length; i++ )
        {
            totalValue +=myPieChart.segments[i].value;
        }
        for( var i=0; i < length; i++ )
        {
            ctx.fillStyle="black";
            var textSize = canvas.width/15;
            ctx.font= textSize+"px Verdana";

            // Get needed variables
            var value = Math.round( ( ( myPieChart.segments[i].value ) / totalValue ) * 100 );
            var startAngle = myPieChart.segments[i].startAngle;
            var endAngle = myPieChart.segments[i].endAngle;
            var middleAngle = startAngle + ( ( endAngle - startAngle ) / 2 );

            // Compute text location
            var posX = ( radius /1.5 ) * Math.cos( middleAngle ) + midX;
            var posY = ( radius/1.5 ) * Math.sin( middleAngle ) + midY;

            // Text offside by middle
            var w_offset = ctx.measureText( value ).width / 2;
            var h_offset = textSize / 4;

            ctx.fillText( value+"%", posX - w_offset, posY + h_offset );
        }
    }

    //legend for status
    if( legend )
        document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = myPieChart.generateLegend();
}
<?
```

[image]

When mouse over the data in pie slice moved from its position.
How to solve this?

Comment: Well this is pretty basic... Have you read this part of the documentation ? http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart

Comment: @bviale,Thats displaying only tooltip..but I need both..

Comment: Can you see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772795/chart-js-pie-chart-slice-data-is-disappearing-when-mouse-over-for-tooltips           This is my code and facing pbm when try to display both.

Comment: @Nithya.K - I've voted to close this as a duplicate of the other (since the other contains code), so you might want to move the image over to the other question. If you are more happy with the answer for *this* question (mine or anyone else's), copy the code over to this question and delete the other. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the chart and move your `drawSegmentValues` to inside the `draw` override, like so

```
Chart.types.Pie.extend({
  name: "PieAlt",
  draw: function(){
    Chart.types.Pie.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
    drawSegmentValues(this)
  }
});
```

then use `PieAlt`

```
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).PieAlt(data, {
  showTooltips: true,
  tooltipTemplate: "<%= Math.round(circumference / 6.283 * 100) %>%"
});
```

and modify the `drawSegmentValues` function slightly

```
function drawSegmentValues(myPieChart)
{
  var radius = myPieChart.outerRadius
  ...
```

---

**Update**

If you have a problem with the labels moving set the context `textAlign` and `textBaseline` properties, like so

```
...
ctx.font = textSize + "px Verdana";
ctx.textAlign = "start";
ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Both is displaying..but now the slice data is moved from its position after hovering..attached screen shot in my question..please take a look.

Comment: That's because your original code is not setting the ctx properties - see update to answer.

Comment: Awesome..simply superb..I struggling for 1 week..thanks for your help

Comment: Can we give slice data outside when overlaps or when data value is small,so that we can see the value clearly..pls share your knowledge about this..Thanks

Comment: I think its a bit difficult (i.e. a lots more code) to prevent overlaps. You'll have to use line connectors and move the label out (even then there will be situations where this won't be enough. eg. long labels). It would be better to just show the labels in the legend, or you could group the smaller ones into a single group called Others and show the split in the legend.